# C++ OOP: How do I avoid type switching?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

#### Background

I am writing a custom expression evaluator to further understand how it works. I'm currently at the first stage of tokenization.

I've encountered the following problem many times before in different programming languages (Python and C#) and I don't understand how I should properly handle this.

### The Problem

I want to turn an expression stored as a string into a vector of tokens that can be used for evaluating the expression later on. I don't want to just store a vector of strings since that'd be a little annoying to deal with during the evaluation.

Here are a few example tokens:

- A number token that stores a value
- An operator token that stores a type of operator
- A bracket token that stores whether or not that bracket is an opening or closing one

Of course, storing these tokens in a vector means I'd have to read the token later on, and this is where the crux of the problem lies.

**How do I create a class structure that satisfies these requirements?**

### Attempt

I first attempted this by creating classes based on what they have and all of them inheriting from a base class.

(The following code only shows the declaration.)

```cpp
class Token {};

class NumberToken : public Token {
public:
    int value;
    NumberToken(int value);
};

class OperatorToken : public Token {
public:
    OperatorType operator_type;
    OperatorToken(OperatorType operator_type);
};

class BracketToken : public Token {
public:
    BracketType bracket_type;
    BracketToken(BracketType bracket_type);
};
```

The problem I had with this was encountered when putting them all in a vector and trying to read from it:

```cpp
using sptr = std::shared_ptr; // Only used for readability purposes in this code snippet.

// Creating the vector is nice!
sptr<NumberToken> num = std::make_shared<NumberToken>(NumberToken(100));
sptr<OperatorToken> op = std::make_shared<OperatorToken>(OperatorToken(OperatorType::Addition));
sptr<BracketToken> br = std::make_shared<BracketToken>(BracketToken(BracketType::Open));
std::vector<sptr<Token>> tokens = {num, op, br};

// But reading from it requires dynamic_cast which from what I heard means is an indication of bad code design due to it being type switching...
for (sptr<Token> token : tokens) {
    if (NumberToken* numToken = dynamic_cast<NumberToken*>(token)) {
        // code for handing a number token
    } else if (OperatorToken* opToken = dynamic_cast<OperatorToken*>(token)) {
        // code for handing an operator token
    }
    ...
}
```

My second attempt involved the base class just having all the different methods from each class as pure virtual methods but.. obviously that can't be right. For example, the NumberToken class would have the operator_type field which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: storing as generic like you did is good, but at some point you have to know which type you're manipulating. So it will be either dynamic cast or an enum, then you cast.

Comment: Use [the visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible in your case, but you could have a `virtual void code_for_handling_token();` that you `override` in the specific `Token` classes and then just call that member function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo there's a lot of merit to this where the object should be the one handling evaluations and such and not the for loop itself, i'll look into it further

Comment: For polymorphism you have two choices: open set of type + closed set of operation / closed set of type + open set of operation. Dynamic cast is worst of both world since you'll have a closed set of type save a closed set of operations. If you want to do anything with your toes, consider a variant. If you want your operations to be in virtual functions, then put all operations in virtual functions.

Comment: In C++, OOP begins when you have virtual functions. Inheritance without virtual functions is immediately suspect. You probably don't need it because your tokens are living in a closed world. Use `std::variant` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you use `dynamic_cast` or something else, the relevant factor is that there is a closed, known set of tokens.

The traditional solution for this is the visitor pattern.

Define a base class for handling a token:

```
struct TokenVisitor {
    virtual void visit(const NumberToken&) = 0;
    virtual void visit(const OperatorToken&) = 0;
    virtual void visit(const BracketToken&) = 0;
};
```

The base token needs to be able to accept a visitor:

```
class Token {
public:
    virtual void accept(TokenVisitor& visitor) const = 0;
    // other stuff
};
```

And each concrete token needs to implement the visitation:

```
class NumberToken: public Token {
public:
    void accept(TokenVisitor& visitor) const override {
        visitor.visit(*this);
    }
    // other stuff
};
```

Then you define concrete visitors containing "code for handling NumberToken", etc. There are no `dynamic_cast` necessary. There is a small amount of boilerplate in the concrete token classes. The biggest disadvantage is putting the "handling" code in a visitor isn't as clear as a simple switch-like for loop.

However, since C++17, there is another option, avoiding inheritance:

```
using Token = std::variant<NumberToken, OperatorToken, BracketToken>;
```

Visitation is as simple as:

```
std::visit([&](const auto& concreteToken) {
    if (is_number_token(concreteToken)) {
        ...
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    }
}, token);

// for explanation, can be done either ways:
template <typename T>
bool is_number_token(const T&) {
    return std::is_same_v<T, NumberToken>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing as generic like you did is good, but at some point (not all the time) you have to know which type you're manipulating.

Dynamic cast works in that case.

The only drawback is that it can be pretty slow as to find which type is really lying underneath, you have to potentially try all types.

I'd suggest an enumerate, so you can use a switch/case statement which is `O(1)`, instead of a series of `dynamic_cast` which would be `O(n)`

This is "rustic", but simple, and works.

```
class Token { 
public:
enum Type { T_INT, T_OP, T_BRACKET }; // more if needed
Type toktype;
Token(Type tt) : toktype(tt) {} // forces to pass the enum
};
```

then it forces to always construct the child tokens with the enumerate.

```
NumberToken::NumberToken (int value) : Token(T_INT), value(value) {  ...  }
```

usage modified as follows:

```
for (sptr<Token> token : tokens) {
    switch(token->toktype)
    {
       case Token::T_INT:
         {
            NumberToken* numToken = dynamic_cast<NumberToken*>(token);
            assert(numToken != nullptr); // safety
            ...
            break;
         }
        ...
    }
```

A Python lexer like `ply` uses an identifier for the type as well. The dynamic cast isn't needed, but just because python is completely dynamic (and also unsafe)

Comment: is the `dynamic_cast` inlined into the `if` statement on my example another way to do the cast safely, or should it be a `dynamic_pointer_cast` to a `shared_ptr` instead? honestly i'm just caring about pointer safety at the moment

Comment: dynamic_pointer_cast is just a nicer way, but does the same as dynamic cast: you have to assert for non nullptr. If you construct your types safely it should always work.